# Rails form_for @form "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the error "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" when I use form_for with a homepage form element. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**home.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @form do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :userInput, placeholder: "Press 'Enter' to move on.", class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**forms_controller.rb**

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController
 def new
  @form = Form.new
 end
 def create
  @form = Form.new(form_params)
  @form.save!
 end
 private
  def form_params
   params.require(:form).permit(:userInput)
  end
end
```

**EDIT**: So as suggested I moved the code from FormsController to PagesController that was already rendering the home page, but the same error still persists. Here's PagesController:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
  def new
    @form = Form.new
  end
  def create
    @form = Form.new(form_params)
    @form.save!
  end
  private
  def form_params
    params.require(:form).permit(:userInput)
  end
end
```

Comment: how do you get the error? by completing the form in the browser?

Comment: Just loading the home page. It's a one page site

Answer (score 0):

Is `FormController` the one rendering the `home.erb.html` view? The controller only has a `new` and `create` action, so i would assume the view should've been named `new.erb.html` or should've thrown an error saying the view isn't found.

In the case of getting this error, it seems another controller is rendering the view, in which that controller should have the `@form = Form.new` instance variable getting set.

Can you confirm the path of where `home.erb.html` lives?

Comment: I believe PagesController is currently rendering home.erb.html. I'm having a hard time understanding how controllers should be setup for a form if it's just a one-page site, every tutorial/guide I can find only specifies it for different pages.

Comment: If it's pages controller rendering the page, then that is the controller/action where you'll need to define `@form`

Comment: So if I move everything from FormsController after the first line under the "def home end" part of PagesController it should work?

Comment: It depends on how you have your routes set up really. If your routes is setup to route the post traffic to the FormController, then no, but if routes is setup to send traffic to PagesController, then yes.

Comment: routes.rb only has `root to: 'pages#home'`, do I need to add something? Sorry this is all very new to me and reading documentation doesn't click for me like trial and error.

Comment: Yeah, there'll be a few things that'll need to be done to get that to work. Rendering the page will be solved by just updating the home action to `def home; @form = Form.new(); end` in your PagesController, but then you'll need a controller or action created to handle the post from the form. I would recommend giving the routes documentation a review http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html on creating a post endpoint for your forms. This may also be helpful: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: Thanks I will. So I can get rid of the def new part and just put everything inside into def home instead?

Comment: That would fix the problem. We can go into details of other ways to do it, but to keep things simple, this would work

Comment: Alright awesome thanks it loads the page again. So I remember from a tutorial on setting up a contact form that I used something like `resources :forms` to make all of the routes for it available, but I just tried that and it's still not saving anything. I also have a model called form.rb.

`class Form < ApplicationRecord::Base`

`end`

Comment: This is where the complications come in. Since you're loading from your root and PagesController, the form is probably trying to post back to the PagesController too, but there's no route set up for that yet but under the root path (i.e `post /` rather than `post /pages`). If your form must be in the root, you can use the url parameter in form_for and reference the forms_path helper (you can doublecheck this value by running rake routes). FormController will need to have the `create` method to handle the necessary logic.

Comment: The tutorial probably covers form creation under a `/forms` path rather than your root path, which simplifies the way things work and keeps things relative to the resource, but since you have your form in your root, things get a bit complicated and weird as you bounce between two different controllers.

Comment: So I still need FormController for everything besides the @form = Form.new? I just realized I didn't have the ajax set up to actually submit the form..that might help too. If it helps at all this is what the front end of the site looks/functions like: http://i.imgur.com/5X9OTTX.mp4

Comment: I think you can just do `resources :pages` and it will route everything thing through pages, but you'll still need to tell form_for to make sure it posts to the /posts endpoints that get created rather than try to do a post to the root path.